# mysql: Shall I change the mysql tmpdir from /tmp to /var/lib/mysql/tmp

Tags: mysql, tmp

Recently on one of the prodcution servers we have seen the replication being stopped due to the space issues on the `/tmp` drive which is having less space allocated.

I would like to move the `tmpdir` from `/tmp[default]` to `/var/lib/mysql/tmp`

Below are what I guess I should do.

1. stop mysql
2. create directory called `tmp` in the location `/var/lib/mysql/`
3. add `tmpdir = /var/lib/mysql/tmp/`
4. start mysql

Is there anything to be taken care of for the permission level of `/var/lib/mysql/tmp/` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
Below are what I guess I should do.

 1. stop mysql
 2. create directory called `tmp` in the location `/var/lib/mysql/`
 3. add `tmpdir = /var/lib/mysql/tmp/`
 4. start mysql
```

You can combine 1. to 4. by restarting MySQL after changing.

About 2., you should put the `tmpdir` outside of the `datadir`.

> Is there anything to be taken care of for the permission level of
>   `/var/lib/mysql/tmp/`?

`chown mysql:mysql /path/to/tmp/dir` is enough.

Comment: As relevant as ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visit this blog for detailed steps with apparmor and my.cnf configurations, http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/12/27/change-path-tmpdir-mysql-server-ubuntu/

First check your tmp dir folder

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

Create a backup of my.cnf

```
sudo cp -pv /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.`date +%F`.bak
```

Create a new directory to hold the files

```
sudo mkdir /mysql_tmp_dir
```

Make mysql user the owner for the directory
    sudo chown mysql:mysql /mysql_tmp_dir

edit my.cnf

replace,

```
 sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
 tmpdir = /tmp
```

with

```
 tmpdir = /mysql_tmp_dir
```

edit apparmor config for mysqld

```
sudo vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

add lines,

```
/mysql_tmp_dir r,  
/mysql_tmp_dir rw
```

restart apparmor and mysql

```
sudo service apparmor restart
sudo service mysql restart
```

To check if the changes worked fine,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

Bingo! And this should display the path for the new tmpdir

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Okay jenny, editing the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended. By default, /tmp will be mounted out of tmpfs and mysql will use this for extra large queries etc. Being in tmpfs means IOPS hit RAM instead of your hard drive or SSD. This improves performance and there is no real downside because the data being stored in the tmpdir is suited to volatile storage. If you are maxing out the size of your /tmp, I would recommend you write your queries to be more efficient or enlarge the size of your /tmp through fstab if you have the RAM to spare. If this solution does not work, then feel free to define your own location of tmpdir and point it towards a disk with a larger partition allocation.

Comment: `/tmp` is not on a tmpfs on all systems, or even a majority of them.

Answer (score -2):

If you make tmp under /var/lib/mysql, mysqld will think, this is database...